# Wanhao Duplicator i3 ABS settings

Tags: filament, abs, warping, wanhao

I am looking to others who have successfully printed in ABS using a Wanhao Duplicator i3.

I have tried and get a lot of warping and delamination. I tried putting a large box over the printer which did help with the warping some but I am still getting some layer separation. I used 235 °C for the extruder and 100 °C for the bed. I am printing at 40 mm/s and 0.2 mm layer height.

If someone has ABS and PETG settings for this printer, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of models are you experiencing these warping problems with? Some things (large and flat models) just can't be printed in ABS regardless of settings, and you should just use a different material. There's a lot more at play than just your settings.

Comment: They were corner brackets for an acrylic enclosure, maybe 1.5 inch square with slots for the acrylic to slide into. The other was an L bracket about 1.5 inches long printed on end. This is where I got the separating layers. I am pretty new to 3d printing and have done well with PLA but want to learn other filaments as well.

Comment: I had the same issue and fixed it by printing a little slower (25mm/s IIRC) and using some kapton tape on the bed. You might also want to lower the bed temperature over time, like described in https://filaments.ca/pages/temperature-guide#abs. I printed at 90 with a longish model and lowering the bed temp stopped my separation.

Comment: I just tried ABS for the first time. I was having issues and I don't have a glass bed. My first four prints failed at the start, so I used Scotch wrinkle free glue stick and my print is working just fine. lol. Thank you Scotch Wrinkle-Free glue stick.

Answer (score 7):

I am an official Wanhao Distributor

By experience I can recommend you to print with this settings:

- Extruder 230 °C
- Heated Bed 65 °C
- Have a glass surface
- Use hairspray over the glass
- Continue to enclose the printer or at least put it where there is almost no wind
- Print at 45 mm/s

Note that this settings vary a lot depending on humidity and other factors related to where you are printing, so it would be very useful to know where in the globe are you experimenting.

Also note that humidity is very very bad for 3D Printing Filaments so keep them sealed while not using them.

Please do  comment if you have any more doubts.

Answer (score 2):

I've had hit and miss success, but nothing I would consider great. I was using Hatchbox ABS with the extruder at 230 °C and the bed at 65 °C and a homemade enclosure.

One thing that did help was making sure the HVAC vents near the printer were closed.